# That is possible to write on LCD a variable?

Tags: microcontroller, lcd

i read the MC21605H6W-SPR3-V2 LCD Datasheet that work with SPLC780D  https://newhavendisplay.com/content/app_notes/SPLC780D.pdf controler.

And i don't understand how can i write a variable character on the screen. Cause LCD character is an address.
That possible to do something like that  ? and how ?

I am using MPLAB for PIC.

```
a = 47;
lcd_write(a);
```

Comment: What you've given there will write a single character with ASCII code 47 (which happens to be a `/` (forward-slash). If you want to write the character `4`, followed by the character `7`, then you need to turn your variable `a` into a string.

Comment: Yes, possible. You can declare a variable and update that. And then print with the lcd_write() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table below is taken from the datasheet you linked:

[image]

For whichever character you want to display on the LCD, you need to take the table as a reference.

Note that the table above, as can be seen, is prepared for hexadecimal numbers. This means that, for example, if you want to print the letter "R" then you need to send 52h (0x52 which means hex 52, equals to decimal 82).

The good thing about the table above is that the character codes match their ASCII codes (e.g. 31h for number 1, or 41h for letter "A", etc). So, all you need to do is to send the characters as text.

In the code sample in your question, since decimal 47 equals to 2Fh (or 0x2F), the translated character will be `/`. So, the lines below will display the same character:

```
lcd_write(47);
lcd_write(0x2F);
lcd_write('/');
```

If you somehow wanted to print the character "G" (0x47) then you need to send the code in hex format, or as a character/text:

```
lcd_write(0x47); // "G"
lcd_write(71); // decimal so 71 = 0x47, but still "G"
lcd_write('G');
```

Comment: Of course, our favourite language C doesn't guarantee that ASCII is used, or even that the letters are in sequential order. The only guarantee is that they fit in a char and that 0-9 are contiguous... _sigh_. Chances are high that your compiler uses a superset of ASCII though. :)

Comment: So C compiler will normaly translate my '47' in 0x34 and 0x37. And i just need to code a function how can set the data pin value, set the enable pin and inscrease cursor.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.

If you want to write contents of a variable, you need to convert the variable contents into a string of ASCII characters.

That's what printf() family of functions can already do for you.

If you want to do it yourself, you need to understand how numbers work. If you have a number 47, it consists of decimal digits '4' and '7', where '4' in the place for 10s and '7' in the place for 1s. So you need to print ASCII characters '4' and '7'.